# Couldn't find network parameters file and compatibility zone wasn't configured/isn't reachable, corda

Tags: postgresql, blockchain, corda, azure-postgresql

Am stuck, trying to integrate azure postgres with corda. I'm using gradle's deployNodes task to create the network locally.

Below is the exception that I get.

```
[ERROR] 2021-09-06T06:53:02,290Z [main] internal.NodeStartupLogging. - Exception during node startup: Couldn't find network parameters file and compatibility zone wasn't configured/isn't reachable. - Couldn't find network parameters file and compatibility zone wasn't configured/isn't reachable. [errorCode=1917kd6, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.5/1917kd6]
```

I had no issues when connected with a local instance of postgres installed on my machine.

Below given is the azure postgres configuration that errors.

```
extraConfig = [
            'dataSourceProperties' : [
                    'dataSourceClassName': 'org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource',
                    'dataSource.url': 'jdbc:postgresql://azure_database_name.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/demo?searchpath=demo_schema?ssl=true',
                    'dataSource.user': 'userN@me@azure_database_name',
                    'dataSource.password': 'pa$$word'
            ]
```

Comment: Did you deploy your Corda Node on an Azure VM, or your node is still on your laptop that connects to the database on Azure?

Comment: It's still on my machine. Once I get this working, I will have to move it to a VM.

Comment: The error is saying that it cannot find the network parameters file, which is needed to connect to a Corda network. Please, update your question adding what you are using for creating the Corda network locally: Network Bootstrapper? So we can be able to help you. Thank you!

Comment: I have reproduced your mentioned error and I have put my answer below. Please, let me know if it solves your problem @user16528894.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

- create a `/drivers` folder in your project root folder. This folder will contain the `postgresql-XX.X.jar` of PostgreSQL
- update your `build.gradle` to add the location of the jar of the drivers with `jarDirs`, like so:

```
extraConfig = [
            jarDirs : ['/your-project-absolute-path/drivers'],
            dataSourceProperties : [
                    'dataSourceClassName': 'org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource',
                    'dataSource.url': 'jdbc:postgresql://azure_database_name.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/demo?searchpath=demo_schema?ssl=true',
                    'dataSource.user': 'userN@me@azure_database_name',
                    'dataSource.password': 'pa$$word'
            ]
        ]
```

- run `./gradlew deployNodes`
- run `./build/nodes/runnodes`
- the node should start (it will take some time since it has to connect to Azure DB)

Comment: I got my network up using the same setup on a VM. But for some reason, it is not working on my local machine. And about the drivers folder, I already have it in my configuration.

Comment: @user16528894 how are you starting the node in your VM? Are you doing java -jar corda.jar, or ./build/nodes/runnodes ?

Comment: I do it the second way - ./build/nodes/runnodes.